# Javascript: Schedule HTTP requests for later

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, job-scheduling

I'm developing an app using Phonegap (AngularJS + HTML5) and I want some of the functionality to be available even when the user is offline.

What I was thinking of doing is when I need to do an HTTP request, check if the device is online. If it is, then make the request. Otherwise, store the request in an array of other requests, and when you go back online start processing all these requests one-by-one.

So, I have created a service called HttpRequestScheduler which looks something like the following:

```
.service('HttpRequestSchedule', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var requests = [];

    // schedule function tries to send the request
    // if it doesn't succeed, it adds it to the requests queue
    function schedule(httpRequest) {
        $http(
            httpRequest
        ).success(function () {
        }).error(function () {
            requests.push(httpRequest);
        });
    }

    // this method is called every time the device goes back online
    function processRequests() {
        while (requests.length !== 0) {
            var currentRequest = requests.splice(0, 1)[0];
            $http(
                currentRequest
            ).success(function () {
            }).error(function () {
                requests.push(currentRequest);
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        schedule: schedule,
        processRequests: processRequests
    };

}])
```

I guess this is a requirement for many apps out there. So my question is, is this the proper/usual way of doing such a thing? Or is there a better way?

Comment: isn't requests.pop() / requests.shift() simpler ? why use splice..

Comment: You still want to signal to the receiving end that their request has to be made. Otherwise they cannot act on when the data arrives. Typically this can be done by returning a promise. Also consider serializing to localStorage.

Comment: @elad.chen Indeed! I'm very new to Javascript and I wasn't aware of pop and shift methods! Thank you!

Comment: You should look into [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker_API/Using_Service_Workers). It is just the thing you want, but sadly experimental and non-standardized.

Comment: Typically I've seen others implement this sort of functionality via AngularJS HTTP Request/Response interceptors.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Good point with the promises. As for local storage, I'm already doing that...just didn't include it here to keep the code shorter.

Comment: @alesc Could you move your comment as an answer. I think it will be of interest to many people and a lot of them will miss it because it's just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To check if your device is online or not you should use [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information). Also when you're using Angular inside a Cordova-like application, [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) will help you a lot !

To answer your question, this a classic problem and the best is to find your own logic mixing an $interval watching regularly the connection via network-information plugin when it's down. When the network connection goes back, you have to execute the list of tasks that you stored in your LocalStorage.

Comment: FYI I'm actually developing a plugin that will include these abilities : https://github.com/ivangabriele/angular-cordova-http

Comment: Actually for monitoring the online/offline status, I'm registering two listeners which are listening for the 'online' and 'offline' events that Cordova is throwing. This helps me avoid the interval that you mentioned in your response.

Comment: The real problem is that online and offline are a a fuzzy concept on a mobile. Being "online" doesn't mean that you'll be able to send your data (especially since your app is concurrent with many others that try to access the network at the same time). In 1 or 2G, you're online, but your app has about 0 chance of sending/receiving anything.

Comment: I rethought it and in fact the best would be to combine both.